# How to search in multiple ways using AutoCompleteBox

Tags: wpf, autocomplete, wpftoolkit, autocompletebox

I am working on WPF Windows application. I want to search in multiple way in AutoCompleteBox. For ex: I want to search by Id and Name in same AutocompleteBox.

Forex:
my table data is

ID    Name

1      aaa

2      bbb

3      ccc

Now, I want to search the table data. I want that user can able to search by both the way i.e Id and Name. either he type **1** or **aaa** he gets the record.

so, How could I search By Id and Name using one AutoCompleteBox?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom filter. As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) states just set the ItemFilter property. It will allow you to define custom method to determine if the element satisfies search conditions. In your example, you would probably implement your Filter method something like this...

```
    private bool Filter(string search, object item)
    {
        var myItem = item as Item;
        if (myItem == null)
            return false;

        // you would obviously check if you can parse search to number
        if (myItem.ID == int.Parse(search) || myItem.ItemName.StartsWith(search))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```